# Dominant rational map and linear systems

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $X$ be a (smooth) projective variety of dimension $n$ and $L$ be an invertible sheaf on $X$ such that there is a linear subspace $V \subset H^0(L)$ of dimension $n+1$ such that the associated linear system (of divisors corresponding to sections in $V$) has no fixed component (i.e., there are no common divisor in the linear system). We know that the corresponding rational map $$\phi: X \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$$ defined by the linear system associated to $V$ satisfies: the image of $\phi$ is not contained in a hyperplane section in $\mathbb{P}^n$. My question is: can we say that $\phi$ is dominant i.e., the image of $\phi$ is not contained in any *hypersurface* in $\mathbb{P}^n$?

In general, I am looking for conditions on linear systems under which the corresponding rational map is dominant. Any idea/hint will be most welcome.

Comment: No, that is not true. Take for instance $n=2$, and a globally generated line bundle $M$ on $X$ with $h^0(M)=2$; then put $L=M^2$ and take for $V$ the image of $S^2H^0(M)$ in $H^0(L)$.

Comment: If $L$ is ample, by Nakai-Moishezon $\phi$ contracts no curve, hence  it is a finite map onto its image, and so it is dominant because $\dim X = n = \dim \mathbb{P}^n.$